# Wrong colors in pygame after setting SDL_VIDEODRIVER to "dummy"

Tags: python, colors, pygame, sdl, pygame-surface

I'm using PyGame to manipulate and draw images.

For example, this is an image I create using [draw.rect](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect):

[image: normal image]

I need to run my code on AWS, so I followed the [instructions](http://pygame.org/wiki/HeadlessNoWindowsNeeded?parent=) to let pygame run on a headless server, and added `os.environ["SDL_VIDEODRIVER"] = "dummy"` to my code.
However now, the images that are produce interpret the same RGB values differently (especially the blue channel).

[image: messed-up image]

For example, the off-white in the original image is (254, 252, 213), but in the second image its produces as a (255,255,255).

Why does this happen?

Comment: There are a few links that might help you, as I'm unable to recreate your problem : http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init                     http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.get_driver

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to enable the alpha channel in PyGame's display.

This can be done by setting `self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), 0, 32)` after display is initialized.